# ordering fields in a table upwards mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

I have a column named **user**. And I have fields like this: user1, user2, ..., user10, user11, user12, user20. BUT fields not always begin by user

I want to sort these fields upwardly, ie, I'm doing the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY user ASC
```

This query returns:
user1, user10, user11, user12, user2, user20

And the sort I want is the following:
user1, user2, user11, user12, user20

how can I do this sort? The programming language I'm using is php

Comment: Was all fields contains `user` and then a number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably better to add another column with the position of the user, and then order by that column. But if you can't change your table structure, a query like this should return your rows in the correct order:

```
SELECT
  tablename.*
FROM
  tablename
ORDER BY
  SUBSTR(user,
  LEAST(
    CASE WHEN LOCATE('0', user)>0 THEN LOCATE('0', user) ELSE LENGTH(user) END,
    CASE WHEN LOCATE('1', user)>0 THEN LOCATE('1', user) ELSE LENGTH(user) END,
    CASE WHEN LOCATE('2', user)>0 THEN LOCATE('2', user) ELSE LENGTH(user) END,
    CASE WHEN LOCATE('3', user)>0 THEN LOCATE('3', user) ELSE LENGTH(user) END,
    CASE WHEN LOCATE('4', user)>0 THEN LOCATE('4', user) ELSE LENGTH(user) END,
    CASE WHEN LOCATE('5', user)>0 THEN LOCATE('5', user) ELSE LENGTH(user) END,
    CASE WHEN LOCATE('6', user)>0 THEN LOCATE('6', user) ELSE LENGTH(user) END,
    CASE WHEN LOCATE('7', user)>0 THEN LOCATE('7', user) ELSE LENGTH(user) END,
    CASE WHEN LOCATE('8', user)>0 THEN LOCATE('8', user) ELSE LENGTH(user) END,
    CASE WHEN LOCATE('9', user)>0 THEN LOCATE('9', user) ELSE LENGTH(user) END
    )) + 0
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/856b3/1).

Comment: fields not always begin by user :/

Comment: @pc_oc yes, user is the column name so it should be okay, see it here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d8ad/1

Answer (score 1):

You can use PHP's Natural Sort function [`natsort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) — Sort an array using a "natural order" algorithm.

Comment: how can I use natsort just for that column? more columns are returned because the query

Answer (score 0):

you need to extract the number with a function, and sort by that

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY numeric(user) ASC
```

here's a quick one (modified from a normalization func)

```
CREATE FUNCTION `numeric`(`str` VARCHAR(255) )
    RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8
    LANGUAGE SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN 
  DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE ret VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT ''; 
  DECLARE c VARCHAR(1);   
  SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str ); 
  REPEAT 
    BEGIN 
      SET c = MID( str, i, 1 ); 
      IF c REGEXP '[[:digit:]]' THEN 
        SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c); 
      END IF; 
      SET i = i + 1; 
    END; 
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT; 
  RETURN ret; 
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this use `CAST`

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(user, 5) AS unsigned)
```

check sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f307c/1

Comment: result: user1, user10, user2, user11, etc

Comment: thanks! but not the fields do not always begin the same way. can begin with other characters

Comment: its depend on string length. if above case 5 char is number

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mysql's [**SUBSTRING_INDEX**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) if data contains the word user with number

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM
  TABLE 
ORDER BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(`user`, 'user', - 1) ASC
```

Comment: the fields may have different names and numbers do not always have

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT * FROM test ORDER BY
   LPAD(lower(user), 10,0) ASC
```

Check here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e49f2/16

Comment: but not the fields do not always begin the same way. can begin with other characters